# Is there a good Q&A platform to integrate into WordPress?

Tags: community

I think my audience is more capable of answers each others' questions than I am.

I need a system for them to do that and I'd like it to integrate with WP so I could use their existing usernames and accounts.

Do you know of a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of [WP Answers](http://wp-answers.com/)? It is a plugin that appears to do exactly what you need.

There are also some themes out there that do what you're after; after a quick comparison, the [Answers theme](http://templatic.com/cms-themes/answers) by Templatic appears to be one of the nicer ones.

Comment: I should add that both are paid options. WP Answers is $89, and the Answers theme is $65 to $99 depending on the license.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one called [Sofa Q & A](http://themeforest.net/item/sofa-qanda-knowledge-base-wp-theme/180802) that was released on ThemeForest a few weeks back.

It looks really slick.

Answer (score 1):

ASK It - from elegant themes 
http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/AskIt/

Answer (score 1):

There is one called Pubble that you can use. Pretty good, works well with WP. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pubble-social-qa/

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! Just a friendly bit of advice...when you're Answering a Question, make sure to check it's date. This one is nearly 2 years old. It helps (for me at least) to *usually* use the "Questions" link above to sort Questions by the most recent.